# create a file in the script using python

Tags: python, createfile

I am new to python.

I wanted to know if I could create a text file in the script itself before writing into.
I do not want to create a text file using the command prompt.

I have written this script to write the result into the file

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as flp:
        data = flp.readlines()
```

however I know that 1.txt has to be created before writing into it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"I know that 1.txt has to be created before writing into it."_ How do you know that? What happened when you tried?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Open can be used in a several modes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), in your case you have opened in read mode ('r'). To write to a file you use the write mode ('w').

So you can get a file object with:

```
open('1.txt', 'w')
```

If 1.txt doesn't exist it will create it. If it does exist it will truncate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **open()** to create files. 
Example:

```
open("log.txt", "a")
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist yet, and will append to it if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Using open(filename, 'w') creates the file if it's not there. Be careful though, if the file exists it will be overritten!

You can read more details [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):